# Firewall rule windows CE ip port range

Tags: firewall, windows-ce, rules, ipv4

I would like to create a rule to allow a port range through firewall in windows CE.
I want to allow these addresses: 10.10.10.1-10.10.10.254

[image]

I tried to make an IP rule with IP:10.10.10.1-254 and IP:10.10.10.1-10.10.10.254, but none of them works.
I tried to make a subnet rule: IP:10.10.10.1 IP Mask: 0.0.0.255, but this is not working too.
I find the rules in the registry, but i do not know how to manually do it

Comment: Find out, I missed the subnet mask:

The right settings:
IP Mask: 255.255.255.0

Comment: You can aswer your own questions ;)